# My title impacts the button on my tkinker gui

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()         
root.geometry('500x500')    
btn = Button(root, text = 'Play', height=5,width=30, command = root.destroy)
btn.place(x=140, y=200)
w = Label(root, text ='Lost', font=("Courier", 50), height=4) 
w.pack()
root.mainloop()#
```

The button is meant to say play on it

[image: The button is meant to say play on it]

Comment: Did you try reducing the height of your Label?

Answer (score 1):

This is a side effect of several things.  What's happening here is that the text in your label is being centered vertically in a box with room for 4 lines.  That text has opaque background, so the bottom of text box is sitting over the top of your button and hiding the text.  If you remove `height=4`, you'll see that it works just fine.

The other problem here is mixing the placement tools.  You are mixing `place` and `pack`, and that is going to cause trouble.  You may need to think about the layout issues some more.

Comment: you can mix `place` and `pack` as long as you're careful. It's mixing `grid` and `pack` for widgets with a common parent that causes problems.